# What is the benefit of an inverted rocket stage?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, launch, rockets, solid-fuel, long-march

For example the Chinese rocket **Jielong 1** has an inverted 4th (final) stage. So the payload sits between 3rd and 4th stage. When 3rd stage separates it has to do a 180 degree turn before igniting the 4th stage.

From: https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2019/08/china-first-launch-smart-dragon-1-small-satellite-vehicle/

> Unusually for satellite launch vehicles, the payload volume is located between the third and fourth stages, with the fourth stage motor and all payloads installed in invert position during launch.

Comment: Just a guess: It might have to do with space constraints. Payloads typically need larger diameters than rocket stages.